# solving parametric differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I want to find $x$ in terms of $y$ by using this equation
$\tan t(u) = y'(u)/x'(u)$, where $y'(u)=dy/du$ and $x'(u)=dx/du$.
Since $t$ is also a function of $u$, I don't know how to solve this equation. Is this possible given $x(u1) = x(u_2) = d$, $y(u_1) = 0$, and $y(u_2) = L$?

I used the following code, but don't know how to include the given condition.

```
DSolve[Tan[θ[u]] == y'[u]/x'[u], x[u], u]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE. To start: 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), since the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) consider accepting the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code.

Comment: DSolve[Tan[\[Theta][u]] == y'[u]/x'[u], x[u], u]

Comment: I am not sure I am implementing the correct code. I just started to learn Mathematica.

Comment: @Min You can edit your question and add  your code. `DSolve[Tan[θ[u]] == y'[u]/x'[u], x[u], u]`

Comment: If you're just solving for `x`, then you only need one constraint for `x`. 2 b.c.s for `x` are too much.  Also, it doesn't make sense to give b.c.s for `y`, because with only one equation, we cannot solve for `x` and `y` simultaneously. (Notice it's impossible to eliminate `y` or `t` here. If they're supposed not to exist in the solution, the problem itself is wrong. ) Is "solve `Tan[θ[u]] == y'[u]/x'[u]`" your original problem? If not, what exactly are you trying to solve?